# "Keyset does not exist" trying to create a CngKeyStore

Tags: c#, cng

Trying to call CngKeyStore.Open() with a non-admin account, and was initially getting an "Access denied" exception.
After granting the user account access to the c:\programdata\microsoft\crypto\keys folder, am now getting the above "Keyset does not exist" exception.

Does the user have to be an administrator in order create keys?  Or can non-admin accounts do it, and if so how?

I can find no definitive answer on this in the MS documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx 
or here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks!